# Add break after 3 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a line where I have the following text: 
U (Rectangular pitch)

What I want is a 
 after the U, so that is after 2-3 characters, so it says:

```
U<br />
(Rectangular pitch)
```

I've tried with this, but it inserts a hell of a lot of breaks :(

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var html = $("span.manipulate").html();
            html = html.substring(0, 3) + "<br />" + html.substring(3);
            $("span.manipulate").html(html);
        });
```

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LzSJD/1/ but I may write it like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LzSJD/2/ or like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LzSJD/3/ (puts the break inplace of first space)

Comment: The problem is that span.manipulate is there 21 times... So it inserts 21 <br />

Comment: So I need it on each span tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("span.manipulate").html(function(idx, html){
        return html.replace(/(.*?)\s(.*)/, '$1<br/>$2')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LzSJD/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var html = $("#name").html().split(" ");
html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
$("#name").html(html);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UJgAa/428/)**